# OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process

Tags: node.js, docker

the full error reads like such:

`Error invoking remote method 'docker-start-container': Error: (HTTP code 400) unexpected - failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./dist/index.js": permission denied: unknown`

this is a pretty simple dockerfile, for just copying everything into the container, compiling and then running the main file (dist/index.js).

Didn't stumble any errors during build time, only when running.

this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine3.14

WORKDIR .

COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./
COPY src ./src
COPY .env ./

RUN npm ci
RUN npm run build
RUN chmod +x ./dist

ENTRYPOINT ["./dist/index.js"]

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

didn't find anything about this specific error :(

thanks in advance